# Standard architecture for iOS/Android apps requiring server-side

Tags: java, android, ios, architecture, server-side

Are there any standard architectures employed when building iOS/Android applications that require server-side functionality? For example, if an iOS app. needs to fetch a list of books from the server side, what/how does it do it? Does it use webservices? Does it use RPCs? What infrastructure is generally preferred for such applications? I've read about ways to encode data structures and objects using things like Protocol buffers and Thrift but nothing about an overall architecture that just lets me code my client-side and server-side logic. Will a simple spring/hibernate web-app work?

I hope the question makes sense and is a valid one.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  There is no single "standard" architecture, there are lots of ways to do it.  Which way is best depends on the details of your project.

Comment: @Mayra I guess by "standard" I mean best practices.

Answer (score 3):

For Android, Google have started to produce tooling around integration with AppEngine using RPC. This Google IO [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U) runs through the new tooling, or the highlights can be found on this blog [post](http://bradabrams.com/2011/05/google-io-session-overview-android-app-engine-a-developers-dream-combination/).